# Cannot read property 'url' of undefined discord.js

Tags: url, discord.js, undefined

I don't know what's wrong in my code, this error not appear everytimes, just sometimes and i don't know why i got this error

Here is the part of code where the error is detected :

```
  const song = {
        title: songInfo.videoDetails.title,
        url: songInfo.videoDetails.video_url,
        thumbnail: songInfo.videoDetails.thumbnails[4].url,
        author: songInfo.videoDetails.author.name,
        viewCount: songInfo.videoDetails.viewCount,
        duration: songInfo.videoDetails.lengthSeconds,
        agelimited: songInfo.videoDetails.age_restricted
   };
```

With the const song, i cant get information of a Youtube video to send a message on discord like that :

```
      const Embedaddqueue = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#008000')
      .setTitle('Music added to the music queue!')
      .setDescription(`**${song.title}** by **${song.author}**`)
      .setURL(song.url)
      .setImage(song.thumbnail)
    return message.channel.send(Embedaddqueue);
```

But with some video, i get this error when i do "!play [https://youtube.com/********"](https://youtube.com/********%22) or "!play [https://youtu.be/****"](https://youtu.be/****%22)

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'url' of undefined`

Comment: Your line staring with "thumbnail:" the "thumnails[4]" property is coming back null. The "Thumbnails" property is an array and you're looking for the 5th element in that array (indexing starts at 0). More than likely there are less than 5 thumbnails. Is there a reason you're looking for specifically the 5th? Maybe just bring in the entire array and sort out later:
`thumbnail: songInfo.videoDetails.thumbnails`
Then later in code sort out the url you need from that array. If it is not an array, just remove the `[4]` and you should be ok.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you resolved my problem !